# multiprocess messaging queue between functions or process python

Tags: python, asynchronous, process, multiprocessing

Im trying to understand how processes are messaging the other one, below example;
i use second function to do my main job, and queue feeds first function sometimes to do it own job and no matter when its finished, i look many example and try different ways, but no success, is any one can explain how can i do it over my example.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager
import time

def first(a,b):
    q.get()
    print a+b
    time.sleep(3)

def second():
    for i in xrange(10):
        print "seconf func"
        k+=1
        q.put=(i,k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    q = Queue()
    manager = Manager()


    p = Process(target=first, args=(a,b))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

    p2 = Process(target=second)
    p2.start()
    processes.append(p2)
    try:
        for process in processes:
            process.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print "Interupt"
```

Comment: no one have idea. =(

Comment: Your code sample have some basic error, not linked to multiprocessing. I think you get an error when you call `p.start` as you pass only one argument `args=(q,)` to the function `first` that require 2 arguments. Moreover, you do not use the `Queue` properly. Its method `put` take only one argument and to retrieve it, you should call `get`. See [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) for some examples. So first should loop and `get` the arguments.